# Can someone tell me what is mobile device certificate authentication in iOS? what is the purpose of using it?

Tags: ios, security, certificate

I am very new to iOS, and I would like to know what is mobile device certificate authentication? If so how could we integrate this aspect in iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im am not sure if you are addressing the same thing as I am about to but this is my point of view on the question you have asked .

If you are asking about mobile device authentication certificates which is not just limited to IOS , it is mainly used by companies to ensure high level security on the devices and networks they rely on . The main idea is to not give access to other third parties . For example if you want to buy some mobiles which will only be able to connect to a certain network of. your company only and is only able to access company wifi and some work related webistes only , we can use these services provided using certificates by certain companies . Take look at this website you might find it a little helpful.

[IOS Mobile Authentification](https://www.globalsign.com.lb/en/products/view/Enterprise-PKI-For-IOS)

If you are asking about Provisional Profiles, that is a totally different thing. Provisional profiles allow you to install your applications /bundles in to your devices . For this you need to have an apple developers account and create provisional profiles using bundle ids certificates .

Im hoping you were asking about either one of them, If not please get back to me and I will help you in a way I can

Comment: Yeah the topic that I am mainly searching for is mobile device authentication certificates. If you know anything about this then just help me out. I agree to your explanation but I want to know more about it.

Comment: could you let me know what things you want to know about? like how they work?

Comment: Assume that you have an application, you need to write the code in such a way that the certificate would be generated and it should sign my data(as of now assume it as a plain text).